# Chrome inconsistent printing across devices

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, pdf, printing

I am trying to print an HTML document of dynamic height to PDF. The document is made up of a variety of inputs and textareas, and I use flexbox for much of the layout. I've been doing some manual testing by filling up some of the inputs or textareas with text and then printing to PDF. The preview contained 22 pages on my laptop. I then tested the exact same file on a tablet and then on a desktop computer. The number of pages created was inconsistent, and sometimes off by a large number of pages. For example, my laptop printed 22 pages and the tablet 28. Why? How can I get consistent printing across devices? I would like to be able to have the exact same physical dimensions in the PDF for the exact same HTML content no matter what device or screen resolution or screen size I am printing from.

Comment: The only way to have the exact same printing across devices is to generate the pdf on the server using something like PhantomJS. Otherwise, you'll always be at the mercy of the device. Chrome on iOS is still webkit instead of blink, for instance.

Comment: Do you know why the device matters so much? Is it that Chrome calculates the size of the content based on the resolution of the device?

Comment: Chrome for iOS probably just uses the the default printing offered by apple's UIWebView, and is thus is wholly outside of google's control (Just a guess). Printing for web is just like designing for web, you describe your site as best you can, but the individual browser/device combos will always have differences. It's the nature of the web. That's why server side generation is the only way to be sure.